# Recommendation for Bluetooth usb adapter

Tags: 11.10, bluetooth, hardware

Which Bluetooth USB adapter do you guys recommend for Ubuntu 11.10/Windows compatibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of them. Every bluetooth adapter works in Ubuntu as far as I know.

Comment: Indeed.  I just walked into a shop and bought the cheapest one I saw; worked fine.

Comment: Hi, when I decided to post this question here, I was expecting a higher level response!, I know that i can buy a Bluetooth USB adapter through dealextreme for u$s2. In this forum post http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1885628, I explain my problems with my tiny USB adapter. Which brand and model do you Ubuntu experts reccomend. I really dont want to use the standard CSR USB dongle, Ubuntu 11.10 x64 just crashes all the time with the dongle plugged in!

Comment: Stack Exchange isn't the place for "as far as I know". 

The linux kernel implements the USB HID API (http://www.signal11.us/oss/hidapi/), so devices can work out of the box without requiring device-specific drivers. That doesn't mean al usb devices are supported however. Niche devices, brandless devices and new devices might not (at least on an older kernel).